# group by operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a SQL table. Where i need to use group by operation. The column to be used in group by clause is a Varchar and i need to replace the column value if containing "cr " or "dr " with empty string and proceed for the group by.

[Table](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PwenZfuw8i34VhBor2sSS/8)
The column - description, if start with 'cr ' or 'dr ' we have to replace its first occurrence with empty.Like 'cr abcd' will become 'abcd' and first two row can match.
Also 'cr abcdcr def' will be 'abcdcr def' only first occurrence if start with 'cr' or 'dr' need to be replaced.

```
**Select description from xyz group by description(replace 'cr or dr with empty')**


 Desired result is - abcd , abcdef, abcdefcr
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table _and also specify the expected result_ - all as formatted text.

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? Are are set functions involved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below query. This will update only first occurrence.

```
Select 
CASE WHEN description like 'cr%' THEN
CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(description, 1,  locate('cr',description)-1),
  SUBSTRING(description,locate('cr',description)+2,length(description))) 
WHEN description like 'dr%' THEN 
CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(description, 1,  locate('dr',description)-1),
  SUBSTRING(description,locate('dr',description)+2,length(description))) 
ELSE
description END  
as Result

from xyz 
group by
CASE WHEN description like 'cr%' THEN
CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(description, 1,  locate('cr',description)-1),
  SUBSTRING(description,locate('cr',description)+2,length(description))) 
WHEN description like 'dr%' THEN 
CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(description, 1,  locate('dr',description)-1),
  SUBSTRING(description,locate('dr',description)+2,length(description))) 
ELSE
description END
```

Comment: It will replace all CR or DR instance. I only want to replace first.

Comment: Ok, then please give more data in example

Comment: 'cd abccr dr def' - should be 'abccr dr def' only.

Comment: Ok i have updated my query. Now its seems worked.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated the database.  In Standard SQL, you can do:

```
select distinct (case when description like 'cr %' or description like 'dr %'
             then substring(description from 4)
             else description
        end) as new_description
from xyz;
```

It is not clear why aggregation is necessary so I changed this to `select distinct`.

Note:  The exact syntax in any particular database is likely to vary a bit from the above.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can use:

```
select distinct (case when description like 'cr %' or description like 'dr %'
             then substr(description, 4)
             else description
        end) as new_description
from xyz;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i did -   SELECT regexp_replace(description, '^cr |^dr ', '')  description from xyz;

Comment: @Learn . . . That is not standard SQL and you didn't specify your database.

Comment: @Learn . . . I tagged the question and edited the answer.  Your questions should tag with the database you are using.